# Getting analytics on custom events for Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

Been reading through the [Firebase Dynamic Links analytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics), and it's clear that the analytics presented in the console will only show three events: clicks, first opens, re-opens. However, I'm not able to tell if retrieving analytics from the API is limited to the same thing. The example shown in the docs only shows those three events too, but doesn't explicitly say that it's limited to them.

Is there any way to get analytics on custom events (for example, a purchase event) for Firebase Dynamic Links?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The three analytics events correspond with the actions you can perform on the dynamic link itself. If the link then leads to a purchase, you'd log that as a separate event from your app itself. The link won't contain that information, but the new event will of course be associated with the same app instance ID and user ID (if set).

Comment: I see what you're saying. I wasn't thinking about it right. I thought that the follow up events would also show up attributed to the link but can see that would get messy really quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three analytics events correspond with the actions you can perform on the dynamic link itself. If the link then leads to a purchase, you'd log that as a separate event from your app itself. The dynamic link won't contain that information, but the new event will of course be associated with the same app instance ID and user ID (if set).

Comment: Will each link have a user ID associated with it automatically, that I can retrieve via API? Or is that something I have to set up manually

Comment: There is no automatic user ID in the link, as that's dependent on your app and the recipient (in case you meant the recipient's UID).